# Error during installation of Magit: "el-get: make el-get could not build transient [make EMACSBIN=c:/Users/.../emacs-26.1-x86_64/bin/emacs info]

Tags: el-get

**In this folder**

`~/.emacs.d/el-get/transient (master)`

**there are** following files for `transient`

```
./
../
.git/
.github/
.gitignore
default.mk
docs/
LICENSE
lisp/
Makefile
README.md
```

**then run** `runemacs --debug-init` from `MINGW64(git-bash)` command line and the following error message shows up:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "el-get: make el-get could not build transient [make EMACSBIN=c:/Users/.../AppData/Local/emacs-26.1-x86_64/bin/emacs info]")
  signal(error ("el-get: make el-get could not build transient [make EMACSBIN=c:/Users/.../AppData/Local/emacs-26.1-x86_64/bin/emacs info]"))
  error("el-get: %s %s" "make" "el-get could not build transient [make EMACSBIN=c:/Users/.../AppData/Local/emacs-26.1-x86_64/bin/emacs info]")
  el-get-start-process-list(transient ((:command-name "make" :buffer-name "*el-

`el-get-build(transient (("make" "EMACSBIN=c:/Users/.../AppData/Local/emacs-26.1-x86_64/bin/emacs" "info")) nil sync el-get-post-install-build)`

el-get-post-install(transient)

el-get-start-process-list(transient (nil (:command-name "*git submodule update*" :buffer-name "*git clone transient*" :default-directory "c:/Users/.../.emacs.d/el-get/transient/" :program "c:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe" :args ("--no-pager" "submodule" "update" "--init" "--recursive") :message "git submodule update ok" :error "Could not update git submodules")) el-get-post-install)

el-get-start-process-list(transient ((:command-name "*git clone transient*" :buffer-name "*git clone transient*" :default-directory "c:/Users/.../.emacs.d/el-get" :program "c:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe" :args ("--no-pager" "clone" "--depth" "1" "-b" "master" "https://github.com/magit/transient.git" "transient") :message "Package transient installed." :error "Could not install package transient.") nil (:command-name "*git submodule update*" :buffer-name "*git clone transient*" :default-directory "c:/Users/.../.emacs.d/el-get/transient/" :program "c:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe" :args ("--no-pager" "submodule" "update" "--init" "--recursive") :message "git submodule update ok" :error "Could not update git submodules")) el-get-post-install)

el-get-git-clone(transient "https://github.com/magit/transient.git" el-get-post-install)

el-get-github-clone(transient nil el-get-post-install)

...
...
```

Comment: Adding the contents of the `*el-get-build: transient*` buffer to the question would be useful. I guess it's a similar problem as [el-get issue #2574](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get/issues/2574)

Comment: Thank you @npostavs. I added more error logs and will check the link.

Answer (score 1):

When el-get is installing the `transient` package required by Magit, it downloads it, enters its directory, and runs `make all`:

```
$ make all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/~/.emacs.d/el-get/transient/lisp'
Compiling transient.el
Generating transient-autoloads.el
  INFO     Scraping files for transient-autoloads.el... 
  INFO     Scraping files for transient-autoloads.el...done
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/~/.emacs.d/el-get/transient/lisp'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/~/.emacs.d/el-get/transient/docs'
Generating transient.info
make[1]: makeinfo: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile:31: transient.info] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/~/.emacs.d/el-get/transient/docs'
make: *** [Makefile:26: docs] Error 2
```

However, it doesn't find the `makeinfo` command. On Ubuntu, try running the command to get more info about it:

```
$ makeinfo
Command 'makeinfo' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install texinfo
```

Now you know what to do. Install `texinfo` and the installation of Magit will work.